# Invoking function with paremeters, one of which is an array of structures in C++?

Tags: c++, function, invoke

I have a program where I have a function that sorts elements of an array of structures by their key field. However, when I invoke the function Insertion(a[],7) - I pass the array and its size, the compiler gives an error expected primary expression before ']' token. I would like to ask what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct CElem
{
    int key;
};
CElem a[7];
void Insertion(CElem m[],int n)
{
    CElem x;
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x = m[i];
        j = i-1;
        while (j >= 0 && x.key < m[j].key)
            m[j+1] = m[j--];
        m[j+1] = x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    a[0].key=32;
    a[1].key=45;
    a[2].key=128;
    a[3].key=4;
    a[4].key=-9;
    a[5].key=77;
    a[6].key=-7;
    Insertion(a[],7);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Insertion(a, 7);`

Comment: `std::sort(begin(a), end(a), [](const auto& l, const auto& r ) { return l.key < r.key; });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you only need to pass the pointer to the start of the array:
Insertion(a, 7);

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter m of the method Insertion is of type CElem*. The variable a is of type CElem* too so you are supposed to give the method just a, like `Insertion(a,7);`.